# Controller class not found in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have the following error while trying to run my controller

> Controller class not found

I have this code in my `routes.php` file

```
Route::get('cms/create-page', 'AdminCMSController@create_page');
Route::post('cms/createpage','AdminCMSController@createpage');
Route::controller('cms','AdminCMSController');
```

And this is the code in my Controller

```
class AdminCMSController extends BaseController {
    public function create_page() {
    }

    public function createpage() {
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: no its working fine for all other controller only problem with this controller and if i change the AdminCMSController to AdminCMS in router and the controller class than its working fine

Comment: It works without a problem with the code you provided so probably you have also something else wrong that you haven't shown use.

Comment: No there are only single class with AdminCMSController and its file name is AdminCMSController.php

Comment: i check the log file and there show the following error <code>production.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class AdminCMSController does not exist' in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_admin\bootstrap\compiled.php:234</code>

Comment: No i did not run this command can you please tell me tha command and how can i run this also tell me about "/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php" what i search there

Comment: I have removed my comments to keep this short and added an answer with the steps that you need to verify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you didn't move the `controllers` directory from the original location (which is `«project_root»/app/controllers/`, you must guarantee that:

1. Laravel's autoload has the `controller` directory. Navigate to `«project_root»/app/start/global.php`. You need to have something like this:

   ```
   (...)
   ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
       app_path().'/commands',
       app_path().'/controllers',
       app_path().'/models',
       app_path().'/database/seeds',
   ));
   (...)
   ```

   Take notice to this line `app_path().'/controllers'`. It must exist.
2. Also, open your `composer.json` file and verify that the following lines exist:

   ```
   (...)
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "app/commands",
           "app/controllers",
           "app/database/migrations",
           "app/database/seeds",
           "app/tests/TestCase.php"
       ],
   (...)
   ```

   Make sure that you have the line with `app/controllers`

If you have this lines and you still get the same message, go to your project root and run the following command from the command-line `composer dumpautoload -o`.

Laravel works with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org), which is a dependency management tool for PHP. It also prepares an autoload file for all your project classes ([see composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading)). When you run the `composer dumpautoload` command, it will create some files within `«project_root»/vendor/composer`.

Make sure that you can find the class `AdminCMSController` in the file `«project_root»/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`. You should see something like this:

```
'AdminCMSController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/AdminCMSController.php',
```

---

If you have changed the default location of your `controllers` directory, you have to do either one of the following steps. However, since you are not defining a namespace in your class, it doesnt seem likely that this is your problem:

1. Use [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) for autoloading classes. Imagine that you have the following folder structure:

   ```
   /app
       /commands
       /config
       /database
       /Acme
           /controllers
   ```

   You have to specify the `Acme` folder in your `composer.json`, like this:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "app/commands",
           "app/database/migrations",
           "app/database/seeds",
           "app/tests/TestCase.php"
       ],
       "psr-0": {
           "Acme": "app/"
       }
   },
   ```

   After this you need to update you composer autoload files with the command `composer dumpautoload`.
2. If you do not want to use the PSR-0 for autoloading, you need to change your routes file from this

   ```
   Route::controller('cms','AdminCMSController');
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   Route::controller('cms','Acme\controllers\AdminCMSController');
   ```

IF you use PSR-0, you need to namespace your classes like this:

```
<?php namespace Acme\controllers;

class AdminCMSController extends BaseController {
(...)
}
```

<sup>Curious about the `Acme` reference? I was too. [Refer to the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation).</sup>

Comment: Thanks milz after see this solution i searh the files which you mention in the solution and find that in the autoload_classmap.php there define the $baseDir . '/app/controllers/AdminCms.php' rathern than AdminCmsController i think this is the problem so i have to change this file i will approve your solution as a test after change the file name in autoload_classmap.php

Comment: Please note that it is not a good idea to change that file manually. That file is created automatically by composer. You must execute a `composer dumpautoload` and it should update your file correctly.

Comment: Yes dear friend i just run the command and than this file is updated if you dont mind can i ask more things from you here or if you can share your gmail id so that i can talk to you

Comment: «project_root»/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php worked for me. And I must say, a very detailed answer to a very common problem. Thank you