# Laravel 4: Model Class not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am getting a `Class 'App\Models\User' not found` error when I try too use the `User` class inside a controller class method. I have looked everywhere and tried everything with no luck! Here's what I've tried:

1. Check that class exists and is in the right path (it works everywhere else)
2. Add `use App\Models\User;` to the top of the controller file and just use `User`
3. Tried: `new \App\Models\User`
4. Run: `composer dump-autoload`
5. Run: `php artisan dump-autoload`
6. Run: `php artisan clear-compiled`

When I do `dd(class_exists('App\Models\User'))`, I get `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php:513:boolean false` which confirms that the class really isn't accessible for some reason.

Any ideas?

EDIT

You will find questions similar to this but not the same. Please read question carefully. I didn't say the controller class was missing. I said a model class (User) was not accessible from inside a particular controller class. And that the model class works everywhere else.

EDIT: Code Excerpt

```
<?php

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Advert;
use App\Models\AdvertPhoto;
use App\Models\AdvertMetum;
use App\Models\AdvertMetaDatum;
use App\Models\AdvertMetaCategory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class AdvertsController extends BaseController {

  /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     * GET /adverts/create
     *
     */
    public function create()
    {
      // New user instance
      // dd(class_exists('\App\Models\User')); // Outputs FALSE
      $userx = new User; // Throws an Exception

      return View::make('adverts.create');

    }




}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controller class not found in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099054/controller-class-not-found-in-laravel-4)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Please read question carefully.  I didn't say the controller class was missing. I said a model class (User)  was not accessible from inside a particular controller class. And that the model class works everywhere else.

Comment: Actually you said "_inside a controller class_" which doesn't imply "_a particular controller class_" let alone "_the model class works everywhere else_". That said, you should probably post the code of that specific controller (at least namespaces, uses and the method where it doesn't work), because it probably has to do with some code on that controller.

Comment: I have added a stripped down version of the controller class. Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you missing the namespace? What about the other classes, such as `Role` and `Advert`, can you create objects of those classes or is it just the `User` class?

Comment: None of my other controller files have a namespace declaration and they work fine. But I did add it while trying to solve this issue but it made no difference. I have just checked `Role` and   `Advert` and they are fine. It looks like it's just the `User` class.

Comment: How are you loading the classes? Please post the `autoload` values of your `composer.json`. Also, execute a `composer dumpautoload -o` and check the file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` and look for any class that has the name `User` or ends in `User`. If you have a duplicate class, that's you're issue.

Comment: I see that your controller doesn't have namespace declared.. Is it the same at the User class?

Comment: I have resolved the issue myself (please see answer). Also to address the controller namespace, they are defined in the root, that is: `AdvertsController` is defined as `\AdvertsController`. This was not my call as this is an inherited project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this on my own. It turns out you have to tell Laravel what class and table will be used for authentication (a.k.a your 'User' class). I didn't know this (plus this is an inherited project). Apparently the `User` class was defined in the root namespace (i.e. `\User`) and Laravel was configured to look for `\User`. But sometimes I see `\App\Models\User` in the code and it gave me the impression that `User` was under the same namespace as the other models since they were ALL in the `app/models/` folder. I have corrected this problem in `config/auth.php` by changing:

```
'model' => 'User'
```

to:

```
'model' => App\Models\User::class
```

And adding namespace at the top of `app/models/user.php`:

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Finally I set an alias in `config/app.php` like this:

```
'User' => 'App\Models\User'
```

So that where ever I've been using `User::blah` will not break (forcing me to add `use App\Models\User;` everywhere!)