# Trait "TraitName" not found in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Working on a project today and out of nowhere I now get the error message

`Trait "PictureTrait" not found`

The traits and classes are definitely included. I don't understand why it says that because I wasn't touching the class that has caused the error

Here's my `start/global.php` file

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/custom_classes',
    app_path().'/custom_traits',

));
```

custom traits folder contains the trait files

[image]

I have tried the following these commands on my terminal

`composer dump-autoload`

`composer update`

No luck...

Here's the class in question that the error is coming from

http://pastebin.com/AF93dNy5

PictureTrait.php code here:

http://pastebin.com/FGpvB2Y9

Comment: Can you also post your Trait code? It might be namespaced.

Comment: You spelled `trait PictureTrait` correctly in the `PictureTrait.php` file?

Comment: @maiorano84 I've added the code to my post

Comment: It might have something to do with namespaces.... Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25100300/908174) which might help you debug the issue.